# Preventing Qty Greater than available

Tags: magento-1.9

How do we prevent someone from adding to their cart or updating quantity a quantity greater than what's available. I'm noticing that on our Magento we can add to cart and update quantity greater than what's available. Not sure how to turn that off. The other post I found seems to update qty to max, but we're looking to just prevent it from reaching max.

Comment: Hello,You mean to say the customer should not add the greater than the available quantity or else he can order more then available qty to cart @Shay Maor

Comment: Yes exactly... it should prevent any addition of quantities greater than the available. Not sure if it's a setting somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, customer aren't able to add to cart product more then quantity available in backend. Unless you have set **Manage Stock = NO**. Check [Manage Stock](https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-manage-stock.html) in dev docs where you can find this setting.

To restrict customer upto specific qty you can configure this in admin.

1 - go to **System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory -> Product Stock Options**, change Maximum Qty Allowed in which can be ordered.

This will fix your maximum quantity order issue site wide ( product detail page, view cart, mini cart etc ).